# How to get first row in Excel SubTotal when getting data from SSAS OLAP Cube (MDX)?

Tags: excel, ssas, olap

I have two measures in my OLAP cube that returns my company's initial stock and final stock.

The problem is that I can't return the first line of the initial stock in Excel's SubTotal.

At the moment it is returning the sum of all the lines as you can see in the image below. In the image it is also possible to see that the final stock has the correct SubTotal.

[image]

Now, in order to have values in the SubTotal of initial stock, I added the following code.

```
SCOPE([Measures].[Stock Inicial Valor]); 
    SCOPE([Data].[Por Mês].[Mês].members);  
        THIS = SUM({NULL:[Data].[Por Mês].PrevMember},[Measures].[Movimento Valor]); 
    END SCOPE;     
END SCOPE;
```

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The Measure properties has [Aggregate Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/use-aggregate-functions?view=asallproducts-allversions).

If you use the Aggregation Function of: FirstChild you will get the "first" data for your Date dimension.

[image]

Possibly your "Final Stock" has an aggregate function of "Last Child".

Generally, the opening stock (also, called Beginning Inventory) is with `FirstChild` aggregate function.

The closing stock (also, called Ending Inventory) is the with `LastChild` aggreagate function.

Comment: Hi @Subbu,

I have change the properties of my measure but it returns null to all rows. I don't know if this happens because my calculated measure was created using a SCOPE.

I try to use FirstNonEmpty with no success.

Comment: Does it work ok when you have a date dimension as well in your query, i.e., monthly data, weekly data, etc ?

Comment: Hi @Subbu,

The values are correct in SubTotal with my Data Dimension. The problem is in Grand Total that in all my attempts are or blank or with the sum of values..